# How to get my one before last revision in SVN?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

How I can get one before revision which i was updated?

> For example, if i have updated on `revision 1`, after that i update on `revision 4`. How i can get revision number 1?

Comment: If you need to constantly switch between 2 revisions as a part of your work you can checkout repo into 2 separate folders, one r1 and second r4.

Answer (score 0):

From the Tortoise menu select `Update to revision...` and enter the revision number. You can also use `Show log` to find the revision number by its comment.

Comment: No, I don't wanna to updated on specific revision, i wanna to see revisions which was my working copies.

Comment: @ZoranMarjanovic well that's not possible by TortoiseSVN. You might have a chance if you are using a filesystem which stores earlier versions of your files.